# QML how to clip image & extract images from single image

Tags: qt, qml

I am having a image which contains numbers in following order :--
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ... i have to show meter reading .. so now how to create sub image of individual numbers from this image so that i can display each number separately .. means to say i want to extract images of number from this image so that i can display them separately on Meter reading  .. please suggest.

Full image size is 108x16 .

I tried using column then using the repeater i replicated the image, but how to change x,y of image inside the repeater so that image inside the repeater is clipped .. so that i extract the numbers from image.. ?

I created column's of the images... using repeater.. but not able to clip the real image.. so that X,Y coordinate changes... and each column contains Digit from the image.

```
Window {
    visible: true
    width: 400
    height: 300
    color: "grey"

    Item {
        id: container
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        width: 12
        height: 16
        clip: true
        property int position: 0
        Column {
            id: image
            y: -container.position * 16
            Repeater {
                model: 10
                delegate: Rectangle {
                    width: 12
                    height: 16
                    Image {
                        anchors.fill: parent
                        source: "files/REE Demo images/odo_font_orange.png"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Timer {
        interval: 1000
        repeat: true
        running: true
        onTriggered: {
            if(container.position == 9)
                container.position = 0;
            else
                container.position ++
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ehmm ... you shouldn't copy my answer into your question, it's confusing ... and you  don't need a Repeater here, it's here just to illustrate the idea,  just replace the `Column` from my answer with your `Image`.

Comment: i tried using your working code ...but should i not use column of images extracted from original image.. ?

Comment: Or you are saying align 10 images... for each number.. 0 to 9 by adjusting the X,Y of original image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should place your image inside a container with `clip:true` and play with x/y of the content item, for example:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 400
    height: 300

    Item {
        id: container
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        width: 30
        height: 30
        clip: true
        property int position: 0
        Column {
            id: image
            y: -container.position * 30
            Repeater {
                model: 10
                delegate: Rectangle {
                    width: 30
                    height: 30
                    Text {
                        anchors.fill: parent
                        verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                        text: index
                        font.pixelSize: 20
                        color: "orange"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Timer {
        interval: 1000
        repeat: true
        running: true
        onTriggered: {
            if(container.position == 9)
                container.position = 0;
            else
                container.position ++
        }
    }
}
```

here I replace `Image` with `Column` item to just illustrate the idea. You maybe want to add some move animation etc.

Updated:
taking you image into account:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 400
    height: 300

    Item {
        id: container
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        width: 12
        height: 16
        clip: true
        property int position: 1
        Image {
            id: image
            x: -container.position * 12
            source: "https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnbEZ.png"
        }
    }
    Timer {
        interval: 1000
        repeat: true
        running: true
        onTriggered: {
            if(container.position == 9)
                container.position = 0;
            else
                container.position ++
        }
    }

}
```

but since your images are not aligned right the result is a bit rough. You need 10 cells with the same size each one.

Comment: Thanks I will try this.. i forget to mention size of this image is 108*16...

Comment: I created column's of the images... using repeater.. but not able to clip the real image.. so that X,Y coordinate changes... and each column contains Digit from the image.

Comment: Your example worked fine.. i tried adapting it to images... and posted the code..

Comment: Thanks ..What do you mean by 10 cells here ?.. also if I create a column I can scroll the images upward.. same as what we see in reading of  mechanical meters .. what do you say ?

Comment: 10 cells for 10 numbers. each cell should be the same size since the offset always the same. in your case you have 108 for 10 numbers = 10.8 each cell that is incorrect if you set width = 12.

Comment: Ok thanks.. in the original example you posted where you are using repeater and column.. is it possible when the number is displayed background image is also displayed.. I mean to say if number 2 is displayed then image behind 2 is overlapped with digit 2.. ? Which we call alpha blending in graphics.

Comment: I am using your original example.. working fine .. but still work with clipping the image & see how it works.. will update in near future

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use [Sprite](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-sprite.html) and [SpriteSequence](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-spritesequence.html). Obviously, you have to set running to true so that you can manually set your desired frame(number) by using [jumpTo](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-spritesequence.html#jumpTo-method) method.

As your image is not 120 pixels wide, it means that your sprites are not the same size. But I recommend you to choose 12 pixels width frames within your original image. SpriteSequence will resize your sprite to its own size if it has a different size. It means that you have to manually set frameX of each Sprite object to get a good visual appearance.

```
 SpriteSequence {
        id: digit
        width: 12
        height: 16
        interpolate: false
        goalSprite: ""
        running: true
        property var sourceImage: 'files/REE Demo images/odo_font_orange.png'
        Sprite{
            name: "1"
            source: digit.sourceImage
            frameCount: 1
            frameWidth: 12
            frameHeight: 16
            frameX: 0
            frameY: 0
        }
        Sprite{
            name: "2"
            source: digit.sourceImage
            frameCount: 1
            frameWidth: 12
            frameHeight: 16
            frameX: 12
            frameY: 0
        }
        //other digits with their topleft and width/height 
        //in original image should be repeated with their own name

       function setNumber(n){
          digit.jumpTo(n);
       }

}
```

Comment: @Katoch   Your original image is not aligned properly. "0" has not a left margin while nine has a big right margin. Realign your original image and crop or expand the image to a multiple of 10 like 100px or 110 px.

Comment: I tried it it is working fine...can i animate when i call function ... digit.jumpTo(n); ... to animate sprites to scroll up .. at present it changes sprite abruptly ... ?

Comment: Means sprites are moving upward animation.. instead of abrupt change of sprite... please suggest ?

Comment: @Katoch, I dont think so. for such effect, you can use a vertical image with an ```Image``` component. But I will prefer ```Tumbler``` from Quick Controls 2

Comment: Can you post some example for this ..? this i foung https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-tumbler.html#details .. but it does not uses images

Comment: @Katoch, You are thinking in the box. As you now have Tumbler option, you can pre-split the digits and put them in separate files. You can also put each of the Sprite controls for each number in its delegate which is far from being optimum. I will send you an example in next 2 days.